# Proxy to trick my local enviroment for preventing Same-Origin error

Tags: javascript, fiddler, same-origin-policy

I call from `http://my.domain.com` WebService at `https://sub.domain.com` and it's OK

When I call locally from `http://local.my.domain.com` WebService at `https://sub.domain.com` it's Cross-Origin request which get blocked in IE or Firefox.

How to proxy it to trick my local enviroment for letting me use it? I use Fiddler.

Comment: Dont you find your question to be at least a little too broad, and a little off topic?

Comment: @Banana No. It's specyfic. How to reroute certain address to anther one in local envarioment.

Comment: Is that actually a programming question, though? <Spoiler>No</Spoiler>

Comment: @Ultra its too broad because there might be multiple solutions with rather long implementations and unless you provide specific code and show what you have done so far to solve the problem, its too broad. and its off topic because its general sotware/hardware question and so far doesnt seem to have anything to do with programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is easily done with Fiddler.

1. Change your client code so that it's not making a cross-origin call. E.g. instead of `https://sub.domain.com/whatever` it instead calls `http://local.my.domain.com/myservice/`
2. Use Fiddler's script feature to rewrite the request URL. Inside Rules > `OnBeforeRequest`, add:
   `if (oSession.HostnameIs("local.my.domain.com") && oSession.uriContains("/myservice/"))
    {
      oSession.fullUrl = "https://sub.domain.com/whatever";
    }`